# why this is giving segmentation fault error?

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, segmentation-fault, sub-array

Why this below code is giving segmentation fault? 
The question says 
Given an array of integers Arr of size N and a number K. Return the maximum sum of a subarray of size K. 
Expected Time Complexity: O(N) 
Expected Auxiliary Space: O(1)

Constraints: 
1<=N<=10<sup>6</sup> 
1<=K<=N

```
// { Driver Code Starts
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

 // } Driver Code Ends
 
    
    
    class Solution{
        
    public:

    int maximumSumSubarray(int K, vector<int>&Arr , int N){
         int M = 1e6+10;
         long long A[M];
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++){
    A[i]=0;
    }
        
        int sum=0;
        long long arr[M];
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
            ++A[Arr[i]];
            
        }
        int l=0;
          for(int i=0; i<M; i++){
              if(A[i]>=1){
                 arr[l]=i;
                 l++;
              }
          }  
            
            
        for(int j= (N-K); j<l; j++){
           sum+=arr[j];
           
        }
        
        return sum;
    }
};

// { Driver Code Starts.
int main() 
{ 
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int N,K;
        cin >> N >> K;;
        vector<int>Arr;
        for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
            int x;
            cin>>x;
            Arr.push_back(x);
        }
        Solution ob;
        cout << ob.maximumSumSubarray(K,Arr,N) << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}   // } Driver Code Ends
```

Comment: Maybe because M x 8 x 2 (and change) bytes in the stack is too heavy to digest? (your algo should be much simpler: just do a for N loop, sum first K elements, then for the followings, subtract the Arr[i-K] add Arr[i], take the max)

Comment: `long long A[M];` is most likely the reason. The entire stack is probably smaller than the size of this variable.

Comment: Don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`, please. It's a very bad habit that should not be perpetuated. If those "driver code starts / driver code ends" comments indicate this is a practice impressed on you by the source of your teaching material, I'd strongly suggest *finding a different source*.

Comment: You didn't list 0 <=Arr[i] <1e6  among your constraints - which is important if you're doing A[Arr[i]]

Comment: @drescherjm Actually, `long long A[M];` is **not allowed** in C++, although, since C allows it, some compilers sort of mishmash the two languages, and it compiles.  For the program to be well-formed, you have to at least declare  `M` as `const` or `constexpr`.

Answer (score 2):

you surely dont mean this

```
     int M = 1e6+10;
     long long A[M];
```

thats asking for 8 megs of stack.

use `std::vector` instead

Comment: I think the problem is that they **do** mean that.

Comment: On Linux, just do `ulimit -s 20000`

Comment: This is ill-formed C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

The array is too large for the stack. You need to allocate the space dynamically. Create a pointer and use the "new" constructor to point to it. Try something like this:

```
long long  * ABig = new long long  [1e6+10];
```

You can also check the error log to see what is causing the segmentation fault. For instance, if you compile this:

```
long long A[1e6+10];
```

you will get "exception unhandled, stack overflow" error.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Maybe your code has some other bug. You probably need to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

> Why this below code is giving segmentation fault?

Since the entire purpose of a segmentation fault is to interrupt your program in a way amenable to debugging, I'd usually encourage you to actually try running your code in a debugger before asking a question. You might figure out the answer, and if you don't, at least you'll have some more information to add to the question.

Having said all that, it probably won't help much when you do this:

```
        long long A[M];
        // ...
        long long arr[M];
```

because declaring two enormous arrays with automatic local scope isn't going to work. Just use `std::vector` for them, as you are already for the parameter `Arr`.

Also, don't declare three variables called `Arr`, `arr` and `A` ... between these variable names and the indentation, your code is virtually unreadable.

Oh, and this line assumes `Arr[i]` is non-negative:

```
++A[Arr[i]];
```

If that's a real requirement, then you should be using something like `std::vector<unsigned>`. If it's not, you should probably bias your index by `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` to get a non-negative index.